# AES Encryption I am trying to encrypt using AES encryption

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, aes

I just want to migrate the ruby code to Java

here is my ruby code

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

key = '7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f45203042350406f8'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-ecb')
cipher.encrypt()


cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-ecb')
cipher.encrypt()
cipher.key = key

crypt = cipher.update('Rahul')
crypt << cipher.final()

puts (Base64.encode64(crypt))
```

Here is what i am trying in Java

```
String getDecodedString(String key,String encodedValue,SupportedEncryptionAlgorithm algoInfo) 
{
    Cipher cipher = getCipherInstancenew(algoInfo, key,Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    try
    {
        byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encodedValue);

        int ctLength = cipher.getOutputSize(dec.length);
        byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];

        int ptLength = cipher.update(dec, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);
        ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);

        return null; 
    }
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
    {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptionHelper.class).error("Security Alert",e);
    }
    catch (BadPaddingException e)
    {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptionHelper.class).error("Security Alert",e);
    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] stringToBytes(String s) {
    byte[] b2 = new BigInteger(s, 36).toByteArray();
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(b2, 1, b2.length);
}

public static Cipher getCipherInstancenew(SupportedEncryptionAlgorithm algoInfo,String keyString,int mode) throws IOException
{
    byte[] decodedBytes;
    Cipher cipher=null;      
    try
    {
        decodedBytes = getBase64FromHEX(keyString).getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedBytes, "AES");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());   
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
        cipher.init(mode, skeySpec );
    }
    catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException e)
    {
        /*Strictly no logging as it is security class 
         *  There seems to be some issue with the Keys so alert it */
         //LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptionHelper.class).error("Security Alert",e);
         throw new IOException("GetCipherInstance does not exsists");
    }

    return cipher;

}

public static String getBase64FromHEX(String input) {

    byte barr[] = new byte[16];
    int bcnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 2) {
        char c1 = input.charAt(i);
        char c2 = input.charAt(i + 1);
        int i1 = intFromChar(c1);
        int i2 = intFromChar(c2);

        barr[bcnt] = 0;
        barr[bcnt] |= (byte) ((i1 & 0x0F) << 4);
        barr[bcnt] |= (byte) (i2 & 0x0F);
        bcnt++;
    }

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(barr);
}

private static int intFromChar(char c) {
    char[] carr = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

    char clower = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < carr.length; i++) {
        if (clower == carr[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works with 32 byte String but not with the 41 bytes in Java but in Ruby it works for any length greater than 32 byte Strange Please help

Comment: Small note: you really don't want to use ECB. Instead of trying to explain why, just take a look at the image on Wikipedia encrypted with ECB: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29. Please use a secure mode, such as CBC or CFB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below Java code outputs the exact same base 64 encoded result from encrypting as the Ruby code and successfully decrypts it:

```
final Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f4520304".getBytes(), "AES"));
final byte[] encrypt = encryptCipher.doFinal("This is my text".getBytes());
System.out.println(new String(Base64.encode(encrypt)));

final Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec("7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f4520304".getBytes(), "AES"));
final byte[] decrypt = decryptCipher.doFinal(encrypt);
System.out.println(new String(decrypt));
```

The Ruby OpenSSL API is apparently only using the first 32 bytes of the key, since the following value for `key` returns the same value as the 41 byte version:

```
key = '7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f4520304'
```

Also, I'm not sure why `cipher` is initialized twice in the Ruby code as it isn't necessary as far as I can tell.

Comment: actually it is 41 bit key that ruby uses that is my main problem I mean it is a code that is going to encrypt it I am still not sure that it removes truncate the key it seems like an Hex String. So my current status is I am able to generate the Cipher but still trying to decrypt the code generated by Ruby

Comment: Cipher getCipherInstancenew(String keyString,int mode) throws IOException
    {
       byte[] decodedBytes;
       Cipher cipher=null;      
        try
        {
            decodedBytes = getBase64FromHEX(keyString).getBytes();
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedBytes, "AES");
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());   
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC"); cipher.init(mode, skeySpec );}
        catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException e)
        {}
        return cipher;
    }

Comment: String getDecodedString(String key,String encodedValue,SupportedEncryptionAlgorithm algoInfo) throws IOException, ShortBufferException
    {
        Cipher cipher = getCipherInstancenew(algoInfo, key,Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        try
        { int ctLength = cipher.getOutputSize(encodedValue.getBytes().length);
            byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ctLength)];
            int ptLength = cipher.update(stringToBytes(encodedValue), 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);   ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
            return null;

Comment: I confirmed that ruby is not truncating the values

Comment: as i am getting different values for different size of the keys

Comment: What is the 41 bit key that you mention?

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I mean that in the actual code Ruby uses 41 Byte key it should be 32 byte, In the code that I pasted in the forum also has >32 byte key but it is Hexadecimal I have written logic to convert Hex to Base 64 that being called before sending it to java.cryptro after calling this resultant byte String is like 24 bytes not sure I am correct on this or not.

Comment: I think I am lost :) -- AES requires a key that is 16, 24, or 32 bytes in length. There is no getting around that. I'm not sure what you are doing in the Ruby code or the Java code to try to get a 41 byte key to fit that requirement. Perhaps you should update the original post with the code you are referencing and format it so it is readable?

Comment: You might want to read the posting help to see how the code formatting on Stack Overflow works for future reference.

Comment: Thanks I m still on not sure that i understand this fully I am moreon the Decrypt logic I have a string how i could convert that in to byte given that it is an encrypted String

Comment: and also My key that has been used in Ruby is for 41 bytes and Hex so it ends up in 24bytes after conversation

Comment: The key detail is that in the Ruby code you posted, using `key = '7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f45203042350406f8'` and `key = '7c54367a45b37a192abc2cd7f4520304'` produces the same output.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that your calls to `String.getBytes()` are doing what you need them to do.

The `getBytes()` method uses the platform's default character encoding to convert the characters of a `String` to a sequence of bytes. The default platform character encoding is something like UTF-8, US-ASCII, or ISO-8859-1. It's not base-64 or hexadecimal.

Most character encodings can't handle the random 8-bit values that are used in cryptographic operations. So, for example, you generally can't create a new `String` from the bytes that result from encryption. Many of the values will be replaced with � or ?, depending on your encoding. And, even if it happens to work on your machine, the machine on the next desk could be configured differently, and will fail when trying to decode that character string.

If you need to convert between binary data and text, use an encoding like Base-64.

Comment: Thanks By the String.getBytes you mean for the Key because when I execute         cipher.init(mode, skeySpec );
I get Invalid key length exception

Comment: @Rahul - Yes, for the key, but also when you take the result of the encryption (a byte[]) and create a new `String` with it (this is effectively the reverse of the `getBytes()` operation). This corrupts the cipher text; you won't be able to decrypt it because some information is irretrievably lost. If you need text, convert the bytes to text with base-64 or something.

Comment: I tried the Key conversation as well but unfortunately I am getting the same error

Comment: getCipherInstancene(String keyString,int mode){
        
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(keyString);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedBytes, "AES");        
        Cipher cipher;
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try
        {
                 cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            
            cipher.init(mode,skeySpec);
        }
        catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException e)
        {}
        return cipher;
       }

Comment: @Rahul - If the key `String` that you are using in Java is the same that you show in your ruby code, it's hexadecimal, not Base-64. That will work too (although base-64 is used more often, because it's more compact), but you need to convert it to bytes with a different API, not a Base-64 library.

Comment: Thanks a lot ok I will try to find a hexadecimal to Byte converter in the Java i am keeping my fingures crossed

Comment: When I try the Decryption it gives me IllegalBlockSizeException

Comment: public static String getBase64FromHEX(String input) {
        
        byte barr[] = new byte[16];
        int bcnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i += 2) {
            char c1 = input.charAt(i);
            char c2 = input.charAt(i + 1);
            int i1 = intFromChar(c1);
            int i2 = intFromChar(c2);

            barr[bcnt] = 0;
            barr[bcnt] |= (byte) ((i1 & 0x0F) << 4);
            barr[bcnt] |= (byte) (i2 & 0x0F);
            bcnt++;
        }

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(barr);
    }